How to dynamically generate text which is `\u1234` like `\\u{code}` in JavaScript?
I want to dynamically generate JSON (from JavaScript) which contains values like this:
["\u1234", "\u4321", ...]

How do I generate that given codes?
const letter_a = "a".codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, '0').toUpperCase()
const unicode = `\\u${letter_a}`

That doesn't work, serializing to JSON it gives:
["\\u1234", "\\u4321", ...]

Is there no way to dynamically generate this sort of data, and it must be written by hand?
I would like to avoid drawing the glyph directly in the JSON like ["ॆ"], because it gets messy with combining characters and such. So I was hoping to write out the \u1234 code point dynamically.
Aha, I guess I can do this:
JSON.stringify(points, null, 2).replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')

But is there a better way?

Is the total aim to produce JSON characters using the ASCII character set only rather than the standard encoding used by JSON? Perhaps you could expand on the problems being faced which were covered by "it gets messy with combining characters and such" ...
